# SQL stored procedure Assistance

Tags: stored-procedures

I am trying to accomplish:

A stored procedure that accepts at least one parameter and updates one or more records based on the value passed in the parameter.  Two update commands made as part of the same transaction.  An error handler that executes if there is an error with a transaction.

With this stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE uspPatByState;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspPatByState
     (@St varchar (2),  @state varchar (2) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM PATIENTS
    WHERE STATE = @St;

    IF @St IS NOT NULL
        SET @St = @state;

    UPDATE PATIENTS
    SET City = 'Los Angeles' 
    WHERE City = 'Honolulu'

    UPDATE PATIENTS
    SET ZipCode = '96801'
    WHERE ZipCode = '55555'

    SELECT *
    FROM PATIENTS
    WHERE STATE = @state        

    RETURN
END
GO

EXEC  uspPatByState  @St = 'CA' , @state= 'HI'
```

But it's not working. I am getting:

```
Address1    Address2    City    State   ZipCode
1831 Universal Ave  NULL    Los Angeles CA  55555
1831 Universal Ave  NULL    Los Angeles CA  55555
```

What I need to see is:

```
Address1      Address2  City    State   ZipCode
1831 Universal Ave  NULL    Honolulu    HI  96801
1831 Universal Ave  NULL    Honolulu    HI  96801
```

Comment: What kind of logic do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what kind of logic you want, or what you want to do. But here is how I would use transactions and error handling:

```
USE mydb;
DROP PROCEDURE uspPatByState;

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspPatByState
 (@St varchar (2),  @state varchar (2) OUTPUT)

AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PATIENTS WHERE [state] = @st)
        BEGIN 
             UPDATE PATIENTS
                SET City =  'Los Angeles' 
                 WHERE City =  'Honolulu'

               UPDATE PATIENTS
                 SET ZipCode = '96801'
                    WHERE ZipCode = '55555'
        END ELSE 
        BEGIN 
          SET @state = @st
        END 
        SELECT * FROM PATIENTS WHERE STATE = @st 
         COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
         SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
   END CATCH;
RETURN
END

GO

EXEC  uspPatByState  @St = 'CA' , @state= 'HI'
```